# Rundeck integration with Ansible through plugin

Tags: ansible, ubuntu-18.04, rundeck

I am not able to configure the rundeck integration with ansible, I am using the rundeck-ansible plugin, but I am not getting easy and useful information/help from google.
I have installed ansible and rundeck on the same server.
I have used that plugin https://github.com/Batix/rundeck-ansible-plugin but not able to configure it. can anyone please share the link which have guide step by step. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep in mind that the [Ansible plugin](https://github.com/Batix/rundeck-ansible-plugin) is out of the box with Rundeck Community and Enterprise, both solutions must coexist in the same server/host to work correctly. So, basically, you need to follow these steps:

1- Configure the [Ansible model source](https://github.com/Batix/rundeck-ansible-plugin#resource-model-source). For that click on "Project Settings", click on "Edit Nodes..." and then click on the "Add new Node Source +" green button. Take a [look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYZYS.jpg). [Choose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rATnH.jpg) "Ansible Resource Model Source" and [define](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe4EZ.jpg) your Ansible inventory file path (usually at `/etc/ansible/hosts`) and Ansible config path (usually at `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`). In the "SSH connection" section you will provide the SSH user and authentication method to access your inventory hosts (you can use the private key path to access your inventory, like the `.pem` file to access to the remote aws ec2 Linux nodes), then scroll down and click on the "Save" green button.

Now if you click on the "Nodes" link on the left panel, [you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAv20.jpg) the nodes defined in your Ansible inventory. Also, you can add another model source to use your playbooks.

2- Now you must configure the Ansible Ad-Hoc Default Node Executor to dispatch commands in the "Commands" section (or use the default "Command" node step in a job). Go to "Project Settings" > "Edit Configuration" and click on the "Default Node Executor" tab, in the left list change "SSH" by "Ansible Ad-Hoc Node Executor", define a valid shell path in the "Executable" section, add the `ansible.cfg` full path in "Ansible config file path" textbox, go to the "SSH Connection" section and select your method to access to your inventory, a common case is to select "privateKey" and provide the private key path, like the `.pem` file to access to the remote aws ec2 Linux nodes.

3- [Now you can run any](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4urRA.jpg) playbooks/inline-playbooks over your ansible node.

I leave a job definition example (with a basic inline-script playbook) dispatched to an Inventory host:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 9cbbdb03-9335-4307-b766-de1f17d81f93
  loglevel: INFO
  name: Ansible Inline Playboook Example
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  nodefilters:
    dispatch:
      excludePrecedence: true
      keepgoing: false
      rankOrder: ascending
      successOnEmptyNodeFilter: false
      threadcount: '1'
    filter: 'name: 192.168.33.20'
  nodesSelectedByDefault: true
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - configuration:
        ansible-base-dir-path: /etc/ansible
        ansible-become: 'false'
        ansible-playbook-inline: |-
          ---
          - hosts: all
            user: vagrant
            tasks:
              - name: uptime
                command: 'uptime'
                register: output
              - debug: var=output.stdout_lines
        ansible-ssh-passphrase-option: option.password
        ansible-ssh-use-agent: 'false'
      nodeStep: true
      type: com.batix.rundeck.plugins.AnsiblePlaybookInlineWorkflowNodeStep
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 9cbbdb03-9335-4307-b766-de1f17d81f93
```

You can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNjcPJeLVxo) video to learn more about run Ansible playbooks (and use inline Ansible playbooks) on Rundeck.

Comment: thanks!!! I have followed these steps and resolved the issue.