# Ansible commands are not run from rubdeck GUI

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, rundeck

I have configured rundeck project with the below mentions link steps.
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60011639/rundeck-integration-with-ansible-through-plugin/60019714?noredirect=1#comment106258813_60019714`
I am able to execute the shell commands like `ls -la, df- h` on remote server as well but when I use `ansible -m ping all` its gives error (you can see in the screenshot) `https://imgur.com/a/ZvJjn2Z` .how I can solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you are doing is calling ansible on all nodes and not all have Ansible installed, keep in mind that Ansible is installed in your server with Rundeck (not in all nodes, is the reason of "ansible: command not found" message).

If you followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60019714/10426011), now all your commands run "wrapped" with Ansible, you don't need to call Ansible directly as a command (check the steps 4 and 5).

Now, about the jobs, just configure a new project and your nodes as it appears [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60019714/10426011). And now you can add inline-playbooks as step or call external playbooks to Rundeck / Ansible nodes. You can do this by adding a step to your Job as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ny3Rb.jpg).

Comment: yeah, you are right. in my case does not needs to "ansible" with command. make sense with your answer.Thank you