# Accessing 2 remote servers in rundeck ansible playbook Inline Workflow

Tags: ansible, rundeck

I have an ansible job that fetches information on one remote server (remote1) and then uses that information on another remote server (remote2).

In Rundeck, I can successfully fetch information from each server individually.

For remote1 (always the same server), the inline playbook looks like this:

```
---

- hosts: ${option.master}
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - shell: cat /etc/redhat-release
      register: redhat_rel
    - debug: msg={{ redhat_rel.stdout }}
```

And the extra ansible arguments are:

`--limit "${option.master}" -i /etc/ansible/hosts,${option.master}:5555`

For remote 2 (different servers called in the Options section, the inline playbook looks like this:

```
---

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - shell: cat /etc/redhat-release
      register: redhat_rel2
    - debug: msg={{ redhat_rel2.stdout }}
```

And the extra ansible arguments are:

`--limit "${option.hostitem}" -i ${option.hostitem}, -e "ansible_user=${option.username} ansible_port=${option.port}"`

But I cannot combine them in one playbook, as in:

```
---

- hosts: ${option.master}
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - shell: cat /etc/redhat-release
      register: redhat_rel
    - debug: msg={{ redhat_rel.stdout }}

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - shell: cat /etc/redhat-release
      register: redhat_rel2
    - debug: msg={{ redhat_rel2.stdout }}
```

Extra ansible arguments are:

`--limit "${option.master} ${option.hostitem}" -i /etc/ansible/hosts,$(option.master}:21716, ${option.hostitem}, -e "ansible_user=${option.username} ansible_port=${option.port}"`

Rundeck error is:

```
ansible-playbook: error: unrecognized arguments: server.com,
14:55:10        Failed: AnsibleNonZero: ERROR: Ansible execution returned with non zero code.
14:55:10        Execution failed: 57800 in project Automation: [Workflow result: , step failures: {1=Dispatch failed on 1 nodes: [rdprod01: AnsibleNonZero: ERROR: Ansible execution returned with non zero code. + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={}, base=null)} ]}, Node failures: {rdprod01=[AnsibleNonZero: ERROR: Ansible execution returned with non zero code. + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={}, base=null)} ]}, status: failed]
```

Note that I'm able to run the Ansible script on the command line but not when I try to integrate it with Rundeck.

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best approach is to create two jobs (for each playbook, dispatching to respective nodes) and call that jobs from a parent job using [Job Reference Step](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#job-reference-step). You can see a good example [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rundeck-discuss/h6XAdkyNWO8/j0_alNZQEQAJ). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60210895/where-do-you-target-your-hosts-in-rundeck-or-ansible) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60101601/ansible-commands-are-not-run-from-rubdeck-gui) you can see why it is a good approach.

Comment: How to pass variable between inline workflow node steps.

 STEP 1:

- hosts: ${option.master}
  tasks:

    - name: Get data on master
      shell: /get/some/data
      register: this_data

    - name: Register dummy host with variable
      add_host:
        name: "DUMMY_HOST"
        MASTER_DATA: "{{ this_data.stdout }}"

STEP 2:

- hosts: ${option.client}
  tasks:

    - name: Echo output from master
      shell: echo {{ hostvars['DUMMY_HOST']['MASTER_DATA'] }}
      register: MASTER_DATA_VAR

I get undefined variable error.

Thanks