# Where do you target your hosts, in Rundeck or Ansible?

Tags: ansible, rundeck

My question is when running a ansible playbook from Rundeck where do i set what hosts get targeted?
In the Rundeck job/ workflow or ansible playbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Ansible inventory you need to add a new Ansible node source. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60019714/10426011). Especially the step 3.

Adding the Ansible node source in Rundeck you can see the Ansible inventory (usually at `/etc/ansible/hosts`) in your Rundeck node list. So, you can use both node sources (Ansible inventory defined before and Rundeck inventory: maybe `resources.xml` file or `resources.yml`),

That means that you can point your playbooks and command steps/scripts to Ansible/Rundeck nodes without problems using "dispatch to nodes" in Rundeck job definition.

Comment: I already have my ansible a node source. I meant in a playbook you say something like `- Hosts: SomeServers` and in Rundeck you can also pick what nodes you wanna run it on. Would i just put `- Hosts: all` in my playbooks and have rundeck set the scope? Or am i thinking about it in the wrong way.

Comment: In Rundeck the Ansible playbooks follow the nodes defined in the "dispatch to nodes" section, you can select all, or just a few, etc. It's the idea to use Ansible node sources :-) the advantage of that is to use single Rundeck steps to ansible inventory and design complex workflows (it's just an example), take a look at this: https://github.com/Batix/rundeck-ansible-plugin#node-executor

Comment: Sorry for my maybe dumb questions but i am just trying to fully wrap my head around it. So to be clear if i have 10 nodes in my inventory and run this:
`- hosts:
    - all
  tasks:
  - name: some tasks`
And filter 3 nodes in rundeck it will just run it on those 3 and not all?
Because then i would just always put all in the playbook and have rundeck take care of where i apply it. PS: New to rundeck if you hadn't noticed :).

Comment: Exactly. You can point to all ansible nodes using tag-based wildcards, etc.