# Rundeck - problem with running commands/jobs with nodes defined in resource-yaml file

Tags: ansible, rundeck

> **[SOLVED - answer in comments]**

I am looking for a help. Maybe someone had this problem already or just have a idea what is going on and can advise? Much appreciated!

In Rundeck I've defined project with Ansible (via ansible plugin) set as a executor.
Within a project I've two resource models:

- Ansible Resource Model Source (with Satellite set as dynamic inventory - all works as expected)
- resourceyaml (*which is not working*)

Configuration for both resources is listed at the end of this post.

As said, I am struggling with nodes defined in yaml resource model -

- node is visible in Nodes section, but whenever I am trying to execute a command or job against it, error is being throwed:

```
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: template
ERROR! Specified hosts and/or --limit does not match any hosts
Failed: AnsibleError: ERROR: Ansible execution returned with non zero code.
Execution failed: 116 in project Linux-Ansible: [Workflow result: , step failures: {1=Dispatch failed on 1 nodes: [template: AnsibleError: ERROR: Ansible execution returned with non zero code. + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={}, base=null)} ]}, Node failures: {template=[AnsibleError: ERROR: Ansible execution returned with non zero code. + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={}, base=null)} ]}, status: failed]
```

When I am executing ansible via cli with resourceyaml file set as inventory, I can see these warnings:

```
ansible -i /etc/ansible/hosts-rundeck-static.yml all --limit node001@domain.com -m shell -a id
[WARNING]: Skipping key (username) in group (template) as it is not a mapping, it is a <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode'>
[WARNING]: Skipping key (description) in group (template) as it is not a mapping, it is a <class
'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode'>
[WARNING]: Skipping key (tags) in group (template) as it is not a mapping, it is a <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode'>
[WARNING]: Skipping key (hostname) in group (template) as it is not a mapping, it is a <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode'>
[WARNING]: Skipping key (ssh-keypath) in group (template) as it is not a mapping, it is a <class
'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode'>
[WARNING]: Skipping key (nodename) in group (template) as it is not a mapping, it is a <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode'>
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: node001@domain.com
```

Conf. for resource models:

1. YAML:

```
Format: resourceyaml
File Path:/etc/ansible/hosts-rundeck-static.yml
Writeable: yes
```

Content of hosts-rundeck-static.yml:

```
---
template:
 nodename: node001@domain.com
 hostname: 1.2.3.4
 username: admin@domain.com
 ssh-keypath: keys/ssh_key/key1
 description: this is a template node
 tags: template
```

2. Ansible inventory:

```
ansible inventory File path:/etc/ansible/foreman.yml
Ansible config file path:/etc/ansible
Gather Facts: yes 
Ignore Host Discovery Errors: yes 
SSH Authentication: privateKey
SSH User:admin@domain.com
SSH Key File path:/rundeck/id_ecdsa
Privilege escalation method.: sudo
```

Ansible conf:

```
[defaults]
strategy_plugins = /opt/mitogen/ansible_mitogen/plugins/strategy
collections_paths = /etc/ansible/collections
inventory      = /etc/ansible/foreman.yml
timeout = 30
[inventory]
enable_plugins = host_list, yaml, script, ini, foreman
[privilege_escalation]
[paramiko_connection]
[ssh_connection]
pipelining = True
[persistent_connection]
[accelerate]
[selinux]
[colors]
[diff]
```

Rundeck version: 3.3.6-20201111, with Ansible plugin version: 3.1.1

Can anyone help me with that? Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Have you followed this guide? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60019714/10426011 With that, you can use both model sources.

Comment: Also, check the YAML syntax, remember that YAML format is column sensitive (also test with XML file model source instead of YAML) please take a look at this: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/document-format-reference/resource-yaml-v13.html#resource-yaml

Comment: Hey MegaDrive68k - sorry for late reply! Let me check above articles and I'll get back to you...

Comment: I went trough https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60011639/rundeck-integration-with-ansible-through-plugin/60019714#60019714 and success! Nodes defined in resourceyaml are fully operational now! My problem was trivial - in 'Ansible Ad-Hoc Node Executor' -> 'Ansible config file path' - I had configured '/etc/ansible' and should be '/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg'. 
Thanks for the tips MegaDrive68k!

Comment: Awesome, good news then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record answer: following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60011639/rundeck-integration-with-ansible-through-plugin/60019714#60019714) guide and defining correctly the `ansible.cfg` / inventory path on the Node Executor section (with filename at the end) solves this issue.