# Rundeck ansible source cannot find nodes

Tags: ansible, rundeck

Using Rundeck with the Ansible plugins. I added to my project only an Ansible Resource Model Source. Within this source I tried several options (even leaving it blank) but no matter what, I cannot get any nodes to popup.
The hosts file is pretty simple and standard and works well with ansible.

The Hosts file (cut short) is like this:

```
[Test] 
ec2-<MY-IP-HERE>.<REGION>.compute.amazonaws.com
```

After saving I get no error, but on the nodes tabs there is no node (with or without filter). I don't use the local, instead I use the dispatch to nodes option.

When leaving the ansible inventory File path as well as the config file empty it should fallback to the /etc/ansible/hosts file. I filled that file as well, but it still does not show any node whatsoever.

What am I doing wrong?

[EDIT]
Just to be complete, this is the output of my service.log:

```
[2021-02-18T09:47:59,623] DEBUG authentication.GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Request is to process authentication
[2021-02-18T09:47:59,627] DEBUG authentication.GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.jaas.JaasAuthenticationToken@54c58c9d: Principal: <myuser>; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: <REMOTE-IP>; SessionId: <NODE>; Granted Authorities: Jaas Authority [user,user], Jaas Authority [deploy,deploy], Jaas Authority [build,build], Jaas Authority [architect,architect], Jaas Authority [admin,admin]

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
fatal: [ec2-<MY-IP-HERE>.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Host key verification failed.\r\n", "unreachable": true}
    to retry, use: --limit @/tmp/rundeck/ansible-<SOMETHING>/gather-hosts.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
ec2-<MY-IP-HERE>.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   

[2021-02-18T09:48:04,172] WARN  services.FrameworkService - Empty node list
[2021-02-18T09:48:07,573] WARN  services.FrameworkService - Empty node list
[2021-02-18T09:48:07,583] WARN  services.FrameworkService - Empty node list
[2021-02-18T09:48:07,588] WARN  services.FrameworkService - Empty node list
[2021-02-18T09:48:07,596] ERROR services.ExecutionUtilService - Execution failed: 282 in project <PROJECTNAME>: No matched nodes: NodeSet{includes={name=.*, dominant=false, }}
```

Comment: Did you check the service.log? ( at /var/log/rundeck/service.log), usually, you can see the reason (reach nodes attempts) and see what happens.

Comment: Also, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60019714/10426011

Comment: I will check the service.log, havent done that yet. I walked through the third step from the issue you mentioned. No errors there, but also no nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're using the correct user to connect to your Ansible inventory (on the Model source section you can define that: SSH Connection > SSH User), also you can define that directly [on the Ansible inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#assigning-a-variable-to-one-machine-host-variables) like other variables to be more specific.

Also, ensure that `rundeck` user (or the user that launches rundeck if you're using a WAR-based installation) can reach the `ansible.cfg` config file and inventory file.

Comment: I did what you mentioned. I placed the ansible directory under /opt and changed the ownership to the rundeck user, but I still see no nodes. Also, I double checked that the key is what was expected. In the service log I find that when I run a job it DOES somehow try to connect to one of the nodes.

Comment: FYI: I just added the log output for the service log, which is confusing me even more.