# RUNDECK - Call a job from a windows project

Tags: rundeck

i have a job, that need to perform tasks in Linux then in Windows.

I've create two project, one on linux, one on windows (with winrm etc)

Seperatly, the job work fine.

But if i create a job to call the linux project and then execute something on the windows project, it's doesn't work.

Playing with the option, the windows server is not know by the Linux project (even if it's setup in the node)
*No nodes matched for the filters: MultiNodeSelector{nodenames=[]}*

or with some option he try to connect with SSH (but it's a windows server)

*Failed dispatching to node WINDOWS-SERVER: Configuration error: SSH Keyfile does not exist: /home/rundeck/.ssh/id_rsa*

So the job try to use the ssh connexion method instead of Winrm defined in the project
[image]

[image]

I tryed with a node intersect, without, with a node defined in the main job.

Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a common scenario, Rundeck allows to use of different node executors in the same project. You can achieve this in two ways:

The easiest way is to define the `node-executor` and `file-copier` attributes on your nodes (assuming that you’re using a `resources.xml`/`yml` node definition) you can obtain a multiple-os node definition in the same project.

For example, for windows nodes you can add these attributes:

`node-executor="WinRMPython" file-copier="WinRMcpPython"`

And these ones for Linux nodes:

`node-executor="jsch-ssh" file-copier="jsch-scp"`.

Another way is to integrate Rundeck and Ansible (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60019714/10426011) answer) using this kind of Ansible inventory:

```ini
[linux_node]
192.168.33.20

[windows_node]
192.168.1.84 ansible_shell_type=powershell

[linux_node:vars]
ansible_user=my_user

[windows_node:vars]
ansible_user=administrator
ansible_password=win_passord
ansible_port=5985
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_winrm_scheme=http
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
```

Comment: It's worked !!!

Thanks a lot !

I add in my ressources.xml the connector and in the job i check in Override Node Filters:
Interection of nodes : No
Node filter: my windows node
Run as Node Step.