# Ansible plugin hostname override

Tags: rundeck

I'm doing some tests with ansible plugin, and have some trouble making connection to nodes involved in the test.

Scenario

1. Using ansible resource model to get vmware inventory data coming from ansible generated json file. HEre, an example of the inventory file (only 1 host are showed)

```
    all:
  children:
    Children_group:
      hosts:
        HOST_XXX:
          ansible_host: HOST_XXX
          categories:
          - VMs
          - VMs
          - VMs
          config:
            cpuHotAddEnabled: false
            cpuHotRemoveEnabled: false
            guestId: ubuntu64Guest
            hardware:
              numCPU: 4
            instanceUuid: 50093acb-b261-28f4-8963-818fb56fc24a
            name: HOST_XXX
            template: false
            uuid: 42090f1d-6a5e-cfe3-2ce7-908633b4d0d0
          config.cpuHotAddEnabled: false
          config.cpuHotRemoveEnabled: false
          config.guestId: ubuntu64Guest
          config.hardware.numCPU: 4
          config.instanceUuid: 50093acb-b261-28f4-8963-818fb56fc24a
          config.name: HOST_XXX
          config.template: false
          config.uuid: 42090f1d-6a5e-cfe3-2ce7-908633b4d0d0
          guest:
            guestId: ubuntu64Guest
            guestState: running
            hostName: HOST_XXX
            ipAddress: 10.240.217.81
          guest.guestId: ubuntu64Guest
          guest.guestState: running
          guest.hostName: HOST_XXX
          guest.ipAddress: 10.240.217.81
          name: HOST_XXX
          runtime:
            connectionState: connected
            maxMemoryUsage: 8192
          runtime.connectionState: connected
          runtime.maxMemoryUsage: 8192
          summary:
            runtime:
              powerState: poweredOn
          summary.runtime.powerState: poweredOn
```

rdeck host, cannot resolve HOST_XXX, because it don't have access to DNS server that is authoritative to HOST_XXX host. Added it to /etc/hosts is not an option, because there are hundreds of hosts in this situation.

Main problem here, is ansible using hostname to establish a ssh connection (ansible way), but, cannot resolve this hostname

Note that currently I'm using ansible model source to import inventory yaml file to rdeck nodes. Image above show the node imported

[node imported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5etb.png)

Ansible plugin tries to use hostname node attribute to connect to node. Instead, we need that ansible plugin us Ip address (guest.Ipaddress node attribute). It is possible ?

Question 1. Can I "override" hostname in rdeck node data inventory (comes form ansible resource model source) using use guest.ipAddress node data to make a connection ?

I tried to use node enhancer, but seems to not "resolve" context variables

[Node enchancer config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GCXW.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to configure the Ansible [Model source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60019714/10426011) (the first step) and then dispatch your playbook using the Rundeck [node filter](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/11-node-filters.html#node-filters) within a Rundeck job (not using the Ansible host parameter).

Additionally, with this, you can dispatch Rundeck jobs against the Ansible inventory.

Comment: Thank you @MegaDrive68k I update original post with more detail. We're using ansbile node source to get rdeck nodes. The problem is teh data that ansible plugin use to make connection (hostname node attribute)