# Issue with using Rundeck to run Ansible Playbook using winrm

Tags: ansible, rundeck

I am having issues using Rundeck to execute an ansible playbook that uses winrm over http to connect to the node.

it seems as though Rundeck is trying to use SSH to connect to the Windows 10 host, as per the failed execution output:

```
PLAY [Create Folder on Windows Desktop Using WinRM] ****************************
TASK [create folder on desktop] ************************************************
fatal: [192.168.10.42]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 192.168.10.42 port 22: Connection refused", "unreachable": true}
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.10.42              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
Failed: AnsibleNonZero: ERROR: Ansible execution returned with non zero code.
```

I have succesfully run the playbook through the terminal (ubuntu server 22.04 lts) and am not sure where to start troubleshooting this on the rundeck side.

I have set the deafult node executor to use powershell for windows environments, and have put the host variables in the inventory variable for winrm to work.

```
#edit below
project.ansible-config-file-path=/etc/asnible/ansible.cfg
project.ansible-executable=/bin/sh
project.ansible-generate-inventory=true
project.ansible-ssh-passphrase-option=option.password
project.ansible-windows-executable=powershell.exe
project.description=
project.disable.executions=false
project.disable.schedule=false
project.execution.history.cleanup.batch=500
project.execution.history.cleanup.enabled=false
project.execution.history.cleanup.retention.days=60
project.execution.history.cleanup.retention.minimum=50
project.execution.history.cleanup.schedule=0 0 0 1/1 * ? *
project.jobs.gui.groupExpandLevel=1
project.label=
project.later.executions.disable=false
project.later.executions.enable=false
project.later.schedule.disable=false
project.later.schedule.enable=false
project.name=Ansible
project.nodeCache.enabled=true
project.nodeCache.firstLoadSynch=true
project.output.allowUnsanitized=false
project.ssh-authentication=privateKey
project.ssh-keypath=/var/lib/rundeck/.ssh/id_rsa
resources.source.1.config.ansible-config-file-path=/etc/ansible/anisble.cfg
resources.source.1.config.ansible-gather-facts=true
resources.source.1.config.ansible-ignore-errors=true
resources.source.1.config.ansible-inventory=/etc/ansible/hosts
resources.source.1.config.ansible-ssh-auth-type=password
resources.source.1.config.ansible-ssh-password=*****
resources.source.1.config.ansible-ssh-user=ansible
resources.source.1.type=com.batix.rundeck.plugins.AnsibleResourceModelSourceFactory
service.FileCopier.default.provider=jsch-scp
service.NodeExecutor.default.provider=com.batix.rundeck.plugins.AnsibleNodeExecutor
```

** Note this is purely for testing purposes, that is why I have only configured http for winrm so far.

```
[winrm]
192.168.10.42

[winrm:vars]
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_winrm_transport=basic
ansible_winrm_port=5985
ansible_user=Admin
ansible_password=Password1
```

This is my job configuration, I have set it to run against the winrm host.

```
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 9e1ce2f2-084f-41d5-a34d-117273d3e661
  loglevel: INFO
  name: WinRM Test
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  nodefilters:
    dispatch:
      excludePrecedence: true
      keepgoing: false
      rankOrder: ascending
      successOnEmptyNodeFilter: false
      threadcount: '1'
    filter: 192.168.10.42
  nodesSelectedByDefault: true
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - configuration:
        ansible-base-dir-path: /etc/ansible
        ansible-become: 'false'
        ansible-playbook: winrm_test.yml
        ansible-ssh-passphrase-option: option.password
        ansible-ssh-use-agent: 'false'
      nodeStep: true
      type: com.batix.rundeck.plugins.AnsiblePlaybookWorflowNodeStep
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 9e1ce2f2-084f-41d5-a34d-117273d3e661
```

I am not sure where I going wrong with setting up this job, but please let me know what I may need to change in order to get this playbook to execute using rundeck.

Thank you!

Comment: You're facing this: https://groups.google.com/g/rundeck-discuss/c/oTy3nvRLSsc 

First, make sure  to configure the Ansible model source to use the Ansible inventory here you can see a full guide that includes how to configure the Ansible Node Executor too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60011639/rundeck-integration-with-ansible-through-plugin

And define your inventory in your ansible.cfg file: https://groups.google.com/g/rundeck-discuss/c/oTy3nvRLSsc/m/UoWe7ku9BwAJ

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this, I just needed to define my host file in the ansible.cfg and it worked right away!

Comment: Great, let me add the answer then :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're facing [this](https://groups.google.com/g/rundeck-discuss/c/oTy3nvRLSsc) issue, basically, you need to define the ansible inventory in your `ansible.cfg` file as follow:

```ini
inventory = /path/to/my/hosts
```