# cant get rundeck to see hosts in ansible inventory file

Tags: ansible, rundeck

I cannot get Rundeck to see my hosts in the default hosts file under /etc/ansible.

I can run a ping successfully through the terminal on the host machine ansible is installed on and am able to run a playbook as well.

This is the project configuration

```ini
project.ansible-config-file-path=/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
project.ansible-executable=/bin/bash
project.ansible-generate-inventory=true
project.ansible-ssh-passphrase-option=option.password
project.ansible-windows-executable=powershell.exe
project.disable.executions=false
project.disable.schedule=false
project.execution.history.cleanup.batch=500
project.execution.history.cleanup.enabled=false
project.execution.history.cleanup.retention.days=60
project.execution.history.cleanup.retention.minimum=50
project.execution.history.cleanup.schedule=0 0 0 1/1 * ? *
project.jobs.gui.groupExpandLevel=1
project.later.executions.disable.value=0
project.later.executions.disable=false
project.later.executions.enable.value=
project.later.executions.enable=false
project.later.schedule.disable.value=
project.later.schedule.disable=false
project.later.schedule.enable.value=
project.later.schedule.enable=false
project.name=Ansible-Test
project.nodeCache.enabled=true
project.nodeCache.firstLoadSynch=true
project.output.allowUnsanitized=false
project.ssh-authentication=privateKey
project.ssh-keypath=/var/lib/rundeck/.ssh/id_rsa
resources.source.1.config.ansible-config-file-path=/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
resources.source.1.config.ansible-gather-facts=true
resources.source.1.config.ansible-ignore-errors=true
resources.source.1.config.ansible-inventory=/etc/ansible/hosts
resources.source.1.type=com.batix.rundeck.plugins.AnsibleResourceModelSourceFactory
service.FileCopier.default.provider=jsch-scp
service.NodeExecutor.default.provider=com.batix.rundeck.plugins.AnsibleNodeExecutor
```

This is my ansible.cfg file

```ini
[defaults]

inventory      = /etc/ansible/hosts
```

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Do you see any clue on the service.log? Ensure to give the rights permissions to access the ansible host and config files to the rundeck user. Take a look at this step-by-step guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60011639/rundeck-integration-with-ansible-through-plugin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rundeck integration with Ansible through plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60011639/rundeck-integration-with-ansible-through-plugin)

Comment: @MegaDrive68k, does it matter how ansible was installed on the hosts system? I have ansible installed through apt and running on ubuntu server 20.04 alongside rundeck

Comment: Nope, just make sure that rundeck user ca reach the host file and ansible.cfg files

Comment: I finally got it working. I had hosts that used password authentication and just needed to add the line ``host_key_checking = false`` and the hosts that I was looking for showed up. I checked the service.log file and saw rundeck trying to run a ping on the hosts and checked the error message. Thank you for pointing that out to me

Comment: Great. Could you post the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Off the record answer: add the `host_key_checking = false` in the `ansible.cfg` file.