# Rundeck Ansible - can't ssh

Tags: ssh, ansible, rundeck

I'm trying out Rundeck in test environment (Rocky 9) and I can't get ssh connection to work correctly. Here's the output with the `-vvvv` flag:

```
ansible-playbook [core 2.14.2]
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/var/lib/rundeck/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /var/lib/rundeck/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.11.2 (main, May 24 2023, 00:00:00) [GCC 11.3.1 20221121 (Red Hat 11.3.1-4)] (/usr/bin/python3.11)
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /rundeck/Ansible_EMS_samples/inventory/hosts.yaml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /rundeck/Ansible_EMS_samples/inventory/hosts.yaml inventory source with yaml plugin
Loading callback plugin default of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/default.py
Skipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.
PLAYBOOK: pb_pingme.yaml *******************************************************
Positional arguments: /rundeck/Ansible_EMS_samples/playbooks/nix/pb_pingme.yaml
verbosity: 4
private_key_file: /tmp/rundeck/ansible-runner430623129543346323id_rsa
remote_user: admin
connection: smart
timeout: 10
become_method: sudo
tags: ('all',)
inventory: ('/rundeck/Ansible_EMS_samples/inventory/hosts.yaml',)
subset: linux_opensuse_leap
forks: 5
1 plays in /rundeck/Ansible_EMS_samples/playbooks/nix/pb_pingme.yaml
PLAY [Sample Play] *************************************************************
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
task path: /rundeck/Ansible_EMS_samples/playbooks/nix/pb_pingme.yaml:2
<192.168.10.149> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: admin
<192.168.10.149> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/tmp/rundeck/ansible-runner430623129543346323id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="admin"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/var/lib/rundeck/.ansible/cp/7beddbbdb6"' 192.168.10.149 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~admin && sleep 0'"'"''
<192.168.10.149> (255, b'', b'OpenSSH_8.7p1, OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 55: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host 192.168.10.149 originally 192.168.10.149
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 3: not matched 'final'
debug2: match not found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1 (parse only)
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512]
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.10.149 is address
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 55: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host 192.168.10.149 originally 192.168.10.149
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 3: matched 'final'
debug2: match found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512]
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/var/lib/rundeck/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/var/lib/rundeck/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket "/var/lib/rundeck/.ansible/cp/7beddbbdb6" does not exist
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.10.149 [192.168.10.149] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: timeout: 10000 ms remain after connect
debug1: identity file /tmp/rundeck/ansible-runner430623129543346323id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /tmp/rundeck/ansible-runner430623129543346323id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.4
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.10.149:22 as 'admin'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /var/lib/rundeck/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /var/lib/rundeck/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: no algorithms matched; accept original
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: compression ctos: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: compression stoc: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:oca1TSCVEzmD98ag0ivhn7bDdABC1yr7LWrUQteVOic
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /var/lib/rundeck/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /var/lib/rundeck/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: trying user hostfile "/var/lib/rundeck/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /var/lib/rundeck/.ssh/known_hosts does not exist
debug3: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: trying user hostfile "/var/lib/rundeck/.ssh/known_hosts2"
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /var/lib/rundeck/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug3: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: trying system hostfile "/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts"
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts does not exist
debug3: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: trying system hostfile "/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2"
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 does not exist
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Host key verification failed.
fatal: [linux_opensuse_leap]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "[Truncated]",
    "unreachable": true
}
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
linux_opensuse_leap        : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
Failed: AnsibleNonZero: ERROR: Ansible execution returned with non zero code.
```

Connecting with the same key outside Rundeck works correctly. Any ideas what's wrong (I'm not running it inside container etc so I'm a bit clueless)?

The main error is:

```
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Host key verification failed.
```

Comment: Did you configure the project using the Ansible node executor instead of the default SSHJ node executor? take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60019714/10426011

Comment: Does this help? https://serverfault.com/a/1110635

Comment: this didn't make a difference sadly - and I suspected that as I'm not running Rundeck in container (noticed mostly that was the setting that bit me when I tried Semaphore in container :D ).

@MegaDrive68k : yes, I've switched to Ansible node execturor as default.